# Can anyone provide a good explanation of "Directx Graphics Kernel Subsystem" and "Display miniport driver"?

Tags: graphics, directx, driver, device, display

Had a look through MSDN to study the architecture of Graphics pipeline in Directx, but haven't found yet any good reference about "Directx Graphics Kernel Subsystem" and "Display miniport driver" !!!

Comment: That should be in a DDK

Comment: OK, thanks...will have a look at that.